# giving border-right a box shadow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to give the border of a triangle that I made with css a box shadow.

```css
#triangle-topleft {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 300px solid blue;
   border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  }
```

```html
<div id="triangle-topleft" />
```

I tried but can't give the right border a shadow. Is there an easy css way to accomplish this?
That's how it should look like in the end (just better with an actual shadow).

[image]

Comment: You want a border to have a border..then no. A `drop-shadow` maybe ....or use a gradient or a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `filter` css rule.

```css
#triangle-topleft {
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-top: 300px solid blue;
      border-right: 100px solid transparent;
      filter: drop-shadow(3px 3px 3px hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 1));
  }
```

```html
<div id="triangle-topleft" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the triangle using a different method. Here I've rotated and positioned a `div` within a container with `overflow: hidden`

You can set the `box-shadow` you want on the rotated `div`, and adjust the values to get the look you want.

```css
#triangle-topleft {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#triangle-topleft div {
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  transform: rotate(290deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -35%;
  left: -80%;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px red;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-topleft">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Update for shadow (not solid color border).

You can combine `linear-gradient` and pseudoelement here.

```css
#triangle-topleft {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  /* gradient for triangle */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, blue 50%, transparent 50%);
  position: relative;
}

#triangle-topleft:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;

  /* gradient for shadow */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom,
    rgba(17, 17, 17, 0.7) calc(50% - 5px),
    rgba(17, 17, 17, 0) 50%,
    transparent 50%);
  transform: translate(5px, 5px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
```

---

#### Solid border for triangle

You can create triangle and its "border" using `linear-gradient`. Suppose you want `5px` of red line width. Demo:

```css
#triangle-topleft {
  /* desired width + red line width */
  width: 105px;
  height: 300px;
  /* subtract red line width using calc functon */
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom,
    blue calc(50% - 5px),
    red calc(50% - 5px),
    red 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
```

You can also use pseudoelement here:

```css
#triangle-topleft {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 300px solid blue;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  position: relative;
}

#triangle-topleft:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  border-top: 315px solid red;
  border-right: 105px solid transparent;
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle-topleft"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
#triangle-topleft {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 300px solid blue;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}

#triangle-topleft::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 300px solid red;
  border-right: 100px solid transparent;
  transform: translate(5px, -100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

#triangle-topleft::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Basically this is taking what you have and adding 2 pseudo elements - `::before` and `::after`, absolutely positioning them, and then applying a transform.

Link for reference: http://jsbin.com/fezutuhulo/edit?html,css,output